# Get information about floating ip pool

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I want to know is there a way to get information about the pool ip addresses that i have in my openstack ? 
i use Havana as version and neutron as network service in a seperate machine

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what information you're looking for, but I suggest looking in this post here: [How to check number of floating IPs available in a pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609785/how-to-check-number-of-floating-ips-available-in-a-pool)

If that's not the information you're looking for I would still look for other arguments for `openstack floating ip` command